# Is there a way to turn off pgadmin version warning?

Tags: pgadmin

Is there a way to turn off the pgAdmin version warning?
It reads:

> You have connected to a server version that is older than is supported
> by pgAdmin. This may cause pgAdmin to break in strange and
> unpredictable ways. Or a plague of frogs. Either way, you have been
> warned!

It's distracting, and takes up too much space in the window.
[pgAdmin version warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09cl2.png)

Comment: I mean if you like plagues of frogs, you could rebuild it sans message and use your own custom build.

Comment: Or, to avoid the frogs, you can upgrade Postgres or downgrade PGAdmin if you are stuck with an ancient PG.

Comment: Neither of these comments are particularly helpful, but thanks. I was hoping for advice on where in the GUI to turn that off, or perhaps direction on editing the .config file. I'll keep searching the web.

Answer (score 0):

The version warning has an "X" (close) button on it, which I discovered by accident.

I had set my pgAdmin4 environment to use the "High Contrast" theme, which renders the "X" invisible.
**If you click on the pgAdmin Version Warning link in the OP, you'll see that the image does not show an "X" on it, but it's there. It's in the center of the right side of the window.

After installing pgAdmin4 on a different PC, with the environment defaulting to the "Standard" theme, the "X" was visible.

Returning to my own "High Contrast" environment, I just 'used the force' to find the hidden "X". (If you hover over that area of the version-warning-window you will be able to see a slight change in display).